# asp.net mvc Create function isn't working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple model:

```
    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get;set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get;set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get;set; }

        public ICollection<TimesheetItem> TimesheetItems { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProjectPosition> UserProjectPositions { get;set; }
    }
```

Note: as of right now, both *TimesheetItems* and *UserProjectPositions* are never filled out when creating a Project entry.

As well as a create method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Description")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(project);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(project);
        }
```

For reasons unknown, unless i remove the if() and the return after, every time i'd try to create an entry in my page, nothing would happen, and the debugger would return my id value as 0 (from what i gather, giving id the [key] attribute should make it auto increment). If i comment the if and the return after, however, the id would no longer be 0, and the information would then successfully get pushed to the database.

From what i gather, ModelState.Isvalid checks the...correctness of the data passed? In that case, could it be, that the unfilled *TimesheetItems* and *UserProjectPositions* are causing this, even though they're defined as not required? If not, what could be the cause?

Comment: How is this related to the SQL _language_? (I see no SQL above. Do you expect an SQL answer?)

Comment: Sorry. Subconsciously added it without giving it much thought. Removed it now.